# cordova build android AndroidManifest.xml bad lines

Tags: android, cordova

I'm extending an ios app to the android platform - I'm unfamiliar with the android tools but following the tuts.

I have added the platform but when I run the 'cordova build android' I get errors on the AndroidManifest.xml

When I trace this it seems that lines are being added in the uses-permission section (see the last 3) that have no android namespace

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

if I add the namespace and rebuild, the error becomes one of duplication. If I delete the offending lines, then the rebuild just re-writes them.

The ios version of my app works perfecto, so I'm assuming its something to do with how the plugins write to this file on android build.

Before I start to debug by unpicking the plugins, has anyone else been here before and resolved it, and are hungry for upvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you need to setup the issue manually as that is not resolved yet, its still [alive](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8401).

You have to open your **plugins/android.json** and remove the duplicate keys in there. In your case search for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`, `READ_PHONE_STATE`  in **android.json** and remove the duplicates.

Then open up **platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml** and remove the duplicate `<uses-permission... />` tags. And then **rebuild** and try again.

Comment: Thanks ridoy. Hadn't spotted the android.json. Useful to know. FYI I just got a successful build after removing the native audio plugin